# When does PHP continue from loops?

Tags: loops

My question is about `foreach` and `for` loop: does it continue reading code if it has finished whole loop, after first "round" or is there any other options?

I honestly didn't find any answers online - I tried at least 10 ways of phrasing. I might just suck at english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `foreach` loop iterates through the elements of an array and performs the operations in its block of code. A `for` loop repeates the operations in its block of code until it is done or a particular condition is met before it breaks out using `break`. Both loops must finish their operations in its block before continuing with any other code unless a condition is met. Let me know if more clarification is needed